# Sig Figs when finding Slope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, error-analysis

When finding the slope of a position vs time graph, do you use sig figs?

For example, if the slope is 150m/10s, would the answer be 20m/s (because the least amount of significant figures in this is 1), or would it just be 15m/s?

Comment: Are you using a watch that only displays the nearest second?  Are you using a distance measuring device that only shows the nearest meter?  Did you use linear regression to estimate the best slope of the line?  There are a lot of details that you haven't declared, so your question is ambiguous.

Comment: This is a question on my homework, and that is all that's given. I have a position vs time graph. And the line is linear. Goes up 150 m and right 10 s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For homework and exams, best not to round your answer unless the question tells you to. The numbers in textbook and exam questions are often chosen so that the final result is a whole number.

Certainly in the example you give $15$ is the correct answer and $20$ would be wrong. You don’t *know* that $10$ seconds is only given to $1$ significant figure - it could have been measured very precisely and accurately and happens to be exactly $10$ seconds.

In real life, things are more complicated. You will need to have an understanding of the sources of your input values and the sources and sizes of errors in order to determine their accuracy.